# Undefined variable: nid

Tags: rules, nodes

I put this code in Rules Action PHP Evaluation. What I want is getting the field_price's value, changing it for negative and returning it for Rule. With this I will be able to charge points because in Rules (Drupal 7) it is impossible to put "-" before data-selector (in this case, field_price's value) and make it negative to charge these points instead of adding them.

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
   $nid = arg(1);
}
   $node = node_load($nid);
   $value = $node->field_price['und'][0]['value'];
   return $value;
?>
```

Comment: Please provide some more information about your rule. What are you trying to achieve? What do you mean with executing it outside the Drupal network? Which settings do your rule have? Also, as this is obviously a continuance of your previous question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/110027/get-value-from-field-in-php, try to make clear what your purposes are from the beginning. All the seperate questions you ask now, won't be very useful for other users.

Comment: Sorry. Now I wrote everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error "Undefined variable: nid" in some cases is obvious. You're *only* assigning a value to `$nid` if the following is TRUE: `arg(0) == 'node'`. If `arg(0)` is something else, `$nid` never becomes defined, causing the error.

Since it doesn't make sense to use `$nid` *unless* it is defined, you can get rid of error by moving the construct where you *use* the value of `$nid` inside the if-test, like this:

```
<?php
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
  $nid = arg(1);
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $value = $node->field_price['und'][0]['value'];
  return $value;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
?>
```

Note that this will return the value stored in the field `field_price` if `arg(0)` is equal to the string `'node'`, and return `FALSE` otherwise.

You write:

> What I want is getting the field_price's value, changing it for negative and returning it for Rule.

Please note that your original code does not do that.  Nor does mine.  I just told you how to fix the bug. The business logic is still up to you.

Please also note that this has nothing to do with Drupal - it is Programming 101.

Answer (score -1):

**Assumptions**:

1. You have a numeric array named arg where you are storing `node type` in even indexes and `node id` in odd indexes.
2. You want to load the specific node into memory and call the member function `field_price` of node object which is a custom field added using the hook `node_field_extra_fields()`.

Now if my assumptions are correct, then the solution to you problem should be :

```
<?php
function get_node_price{
if ($arg[0] == 'node') {
   $nid = $arg[1];
}
   $node = node_load($nid,NULL,FALSE);
   //Not sure whether the args and the method are correct here as it's custom.
   $value = $node->field_price['und'][0]['value'];
   return $value;
}
?>
```

Comment: Reasons for downvote: 1) It does *not* fix the bug in the OPs code. 2) It wraps the OPs buggy code in a function. This is not how [PHP Evaluation inside Rules](https://groups.drupal.org/node/148934) work. 3) It is pointless to pass additional arguments to `node_load` that are the same as the defaults.